# here api request error --- Invalid credentials

Tags: here-api

I have a 90-day trial and I am registered at (Evaluation 2018-06-29).
But when I request with my correct copied app id and app code I get the below error.

```
{
  "response": {
    "_type": "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
    "type": "PermissionError",
    "subtype": "InvalidCredentials",
    "details": "This is not a valid app_id and app_code pair. Please verify that the values are not swapped between the app_id and app_code and the values provisioned by HERE (either by your customer representative or via http://developer.here.com/myapps) were copied correctly into the request.",
    "metaInfo": {
      "timestamp": "2018-08-15T18:52:35Z",
      "mapVersion": "8.30.86.153",
      "moduleVersion": "7.2.201832-36299",
      "interfaceVersion": "2.6.34"
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help, especially someone from here api developer support team?

Comment: We now offer a free account that has replaced the 90 day trials.  It's referred to as the "Freemium" account and it will allow you to pretty much have ongoing free access (limited to 250k monthly transactions).   Please visit https://developer.here.com/plans for more information and to receive new app_id/app_code credentials.  We apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed it to freemium user, but unfortunately I still get the same answer, even if I update my ID information. Can you help?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the REST API request you are sending?  (without the app_id and app_code)

Answer (score 0):

Go into [your account projects](https://developer.here.com/projects) and add a new project explicitly for the Freemium plan.  Then you should be able to generate a new JavaScript/REST **App ID** and **App Code**.  If you are using one of the mobile SDKs you would generate a new id / code there as well.

**(1) Copy and Paste**

I'm not certain this is what may be happening for you, but one of my codes had a leading underscore and it was very easy to copy and paste it incorrectly into my source code.

**(2) Domain Protection**

Also make sure that if you checked "Secure app credentials against a specific domain" that you are calling the routing service from the same domain.

**(3) Shell Interpolation**

Without more detail about how you are making the calls to the routing service (curl, postman, javascript, ios, android, etc.) it may also indicate where to offer advice.

For example, if you are using `curl` make sure your parameters have surrounding quotes as `&` will be interpreted by a shell such that `?app_id=your-app-id&app_code=your-app-code` is not interpreted properly.  That could generate the response you saw as the shell took your app_code parameter away before `curl` could make the request only passing the app_id.